# Unable to install net-snmp of ubuntu 16.04 : error received

Tags: 16.04

I have tried several times but unable to install net-snmp on Ubuntu 16.04i cant understand at all what is the issue . Please any help will be more than welcome :

net-snmp directory name :

net-snmp-5.7.3+dfsg

```
output of ./configure

---------------------------------------------------------
            Net-SNMP configuration summary:
---------------------------------------------------------

  SNMP Versions Supported:    1 2c 3
  Building for:               linux
  Net-SNMP Version:           5.7.3
  Network transport support:  Callback Unix Alias TCP UDP IPv4Base SocketBase TCPBase UDPIPv4Base UDPBase
  SNMPv3 Security Modules:     usm
  Agent MIB code:            default_modules =>  snmpv3mibs mibII ucd_snmp notification notification-log-mib target agent_mibs agentx disman/event disman/schedule utilities host
  MYSQL Trap Logging:         unavailable
  Embedded Perl support:      disabled
  SNMP Perl modules:          building -- not embeddable
  SNMP Python modules:        disabled
  Crypto support from:        crypto
  Authentication support:     MD5 SHA1
  Encryption support:         DES AES
  Local DNSSEC validation:    disabled


Error Received :
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lperl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:976: recipe for target 'libnetsnmpagent.la' failed
make[1]: *** [libnetsnmpagent.la] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/siaetest/net-snmp-5.7.3+dfsg/agent'
Makefile:852: recipe for target 'installsubdirlibs' failed
make: *** [installsubdirlibs] Error 1


sudo apt-cache search net-snmp
libnet-snmp-perl - Script SNMP connections
libsnmp-base - SNMP configuration script, MIBs and documentation
libsnmp-dev - SNMP (Simple Network Management Protocol) development files
libsnmp30 - SNMP (Simple Network Management Protocol) library
libsnmp30-dbg - SNMP (Simple Network Management Protocol) library debug
snmp - SNMP (Simple Network Management Protocol) applications
snmpd - SNMP (Simple Network Management Protocol) agents
libsnmp-extension-passpersist-perl - Generic pass/pass_persist extension framework for Net-SNMP
libsnmp-perl - SNMP (Simple Network Management Protocol) Perl5 support
python-netsnmp - SNMP (Simple Network Management Protocol) Python support
ruby-snmp - simple network management protocol bindings for ruby
snmptrapd - Net-SNMP notification receiver
snmptt - SNMP trap handler for use with snmptrapd
tkmib - SNMP (Simple Network Management Protocol) MIB browser
```

Comment: any help is appreciated guys !

Comment: please help on this

Comment: Guys i really need help on this , any inputs are more than welcome

Comment: Why are you trying to compile it? Why not simply install it from the repositories?

Comment: how ,please guide me , i have not internet connection

Comment: Get a working internet connection. You'll have to install build dependencies to compile net-snmp anyway - which will require internet access.

Comment: thanks buddy  but its certainly not gonna happen as device is in DMZ , looks like i have no other way

Comment: No means of installing packages also means no security updates. That's very bad. I would start by getting access to Ubuntu repositories somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved this issue through normal way :

```
./configure

make

sudo make install
```

I then typed snmpget --version

and i got reply "NET-SNMP version: 5.7.3"

primarily the issue was resolved with the workaround by manually creating the symlink with ln -s /usr/lib/libperl.so.5.22 /usr/lib/libperl.so
and it links correctly.

please read below link which was helpful :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17576911/cannot-find-lperl-doing-a-makefile-on-c

Thanks everyone for the effort

Answer (score 1):

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lperl

This is the linker, complaining that it can't find perl libraries.

To install the perl libraries, run `sudo apt install libperl-devel`.

But as you do not have internet connectivity, this is probably not possible. You can download the package from [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libperl-dev), but it must match other installed perl packages - which in a offline system requires some tracking down.

You write that you have the machine in a DMZ. You should configure some way for the machine to reach internet, to get updates and install software. This can be via an [apt proxy](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptProxy), which will behave like a local mirror, without the overhead to mirror all packages that you don't need.

Running machines without access to updates is considered a security risk - and as you've discovered, makes installing software more difficult.

Comment: ok  any way to run below commands through python -netsnmp:
snmpset -v1 -c SYSTEM 172.22.11.101 1.3.6.1.4.1.3373.900.2.5.2.1.2.127.0.0.1.83.89.83.84.69.77 s STRING

#set relay OFF of power device -> switch OFF the power to DUT (10.22.11.16)
snmpset -v1 -c SYSTEM 172.22.11.101 1.3.6.1.4.1.3373.900.2.3.1.1.3.1 i 1

#set relay ON of power device -> switch ON the power to DUT (10.22.11.16)
snmpset -v1 -c SYSTEM 172.22.11.101 1.3.6.1.4.1.3373.900.2.3.1.1.3.1 i 2

#logout to power device
snmpset -v1 -c SYSTEM 172.22.11.101 1.3.6.1.4.1.3373.900.2.5.2.1.3.127.0.0.1.83.89.83.84.69.77 i 2

Comment: Fix your install so that you're able to install software and security updates the normal way. Then use whatever tool you want. Python-modules for SNMP are plentiful, but they must be installed.

Comment: buddy i have python-netsnmp hence i asked if i can use it as a work around